# When I import images on drawable folder and try to use the images on Image view the app crashes. However, when I set of Images the app works fine

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to add an image in my app. When I add an image from the drawable folder the app crashes. I am using android studio 3.4.1.

The main activity:

```
package com.example.tiktaktoegame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void ImageHandler (View view){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("Result","Working");
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="231dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:onClick="ImageHandler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/i4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/i1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:onClick="ImageHandler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/i4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/i2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/i0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:onClick="ImageHandler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/i5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/i1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="168dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:onClick="ImageHandler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/i5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/i5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/i4" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="268dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/i8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/i6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/i1" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/i8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/i3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/i2" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:onClick="ImageHandler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/i7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/i4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/i3" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
        android:onClick="ImageHandler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/i4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/i4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/i4" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/i8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:onClick="ImageHandler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/i4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/i5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baord"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-17dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tiktaktoegame, PID: 8893
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tiktaktoegame/com.example.tiktaktoegame.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.tiktaktoegame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060055
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.tiktaktoegame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: `@drawable/baord` - does that exist as typed?

Comment: is your image a vector drawable or png ? and which folder is it in ?

Comment: @Andy Yes, it does.

Comment: @ismailalaoui It is in drawable folder on res. It is a jpg file.

Comment: what device are you testing with ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui Nexus S and Pixel XL with API  22.

Comment: You should put in the `drawable` folder not `drawable-24`. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have the Error `inflating class ImageView at android.view.LayoutInflater.` as i can read from your comment your are using a lollipop device .

please replace :

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/baord"
```

with :

```
app:src="@drawable/baord"
```

check also the size of the image , a bigger image can cause the issue , to make sure use small image instead

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
```

Perhaps your drawable resource `@drawable/baord` is typo or not exist?

Or another possibility is you put your image in `drawable-v24` folder not `drawable` folder. You could check in the structure window, change from Android to Project type

Comment: It exists on the drawable folder and yes the file is named baord.

Comment: I've updated my answer, could you check the `project` structure of your folder? Perhaps you put the image in `drawable-v24` folder when you paste it.